# Customizing WSO2 IS login error messages

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 5.2.  I have created a custom UserStoreManager that extends JDBCUserStoreManager and is readonly.  Here is a snippet from user-mgt.xml.

```
    <UserStoreManager class="org.arbfile.wso2.user.ReadOnlyJDBCUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">false</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">false</Property>
        ........
    </UserStoreManager>
```

In terms of user authentication, I'm doing user/passw verification in the doAuthenticate() method of my custom class.  I'm also doing other checks like IP filtering and user account locked.  I can throw UserStoreException  when these other items fail.  The problem I'm having is setting the appropriate error message based on certain failure conditions.  I found the following link https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Authentication+Error+Messages, however the information is too vague.  I need to know how to set a "new" custom error message so the authentication endpoint can pass it to the login.jsp where it is rendered.  Right now I get the exact same error message no matter what error occurs.

**EDIT**: Adding html form code for clarity:

```
<form action="../commonauth" method="post" id="loginForm">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="0" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionDataKey" value='e04168f9-95c7-4b87-93af-60e1ecdc6273'/>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="wr-btn green-ltgr col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 uppercase font-extra-large" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am using SAML and this is the form presented for form based login on the WSO2 server.  The form action is "../commonauth".  The form submission with username and password appears to be going against a different web app (and not the authenticationendpoint web app).  The above code comes from basicauth.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Few months ago I had exactly same requirement but could not found proper solution. I found that **BasicAutheticator** every time sending the same error code to login page. As a workaround I changed my flow a little and decided to customize the login app instead of customizing WSO2 error code. I know it is a wrong practice but it solved my problem. Here is how my new architecture works.

1. I created a library with all logic of pre authentication checks, lets name it validation.jar
2. Then I added this library as maven dependency to login application which is **authenticationendpoint**.
3. Created a new servlet in login app, let's name it PreValidation.java
4. Modified the basicAuth.jsp and instead of submitting the form to /samlsso, Submitted the form to **PreValidation** servlet.
5. In PreValidation servlet, with the help of validation.jar do all validations except authentication ( which should be the task of WSO2).
6. If any Validation is failed, pass the corresponding error code back to to login.jsp and show the message on screen.
7. If all validations are done, submit the request to WSO2 and let the flow continue.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I follow until step 4.  basicAuth.jsp has form action ../commonauth not /samlsso.  commonauth does the real work here.  It must call my custom doAuthenticate() and then it redirects back to login.do on error.  I need to be able to inject my own class somewhere in this process flow.

Comment: I am using SSO/SAML

Comment: Form action depends on type of protocol you are using for SSO. In my case, I was using saml, hence the action was /samlsso. Now, the above solution is to just do pre-authentication checks and show error messages on login page like IP filtering and user account locked, which was the problem you explained in the question. Think it as a extra layer of validation before you finally submit client credentials to WSO2. Ofcourse you can also use your custom logic to authenticate the user as you already did.

Answer (score 0):

Once the error codes are enabled from [application-authentication.xml](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Customizing+Authentication+Error+Messages) You can edit following JSPs to display error messages.

- Login failed BasicAuth:- [IS_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\webapps\authenticationendpoint\basicauth.jsp
- Remaining Attempts are over :- [IS_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\webapps\authenticationendpoint\retry.jsp

Please take a look at the URL in Get request. It contains the relevant error code. Hope this helps someone.